# Read HTML from WebView - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

Do we have a way to read html loaded into Xamarin Forms WebView?

I have loaded URL into a xamarin forms WebView and now that url changes on webview and I want to find a page when there is a redirection. I need to read html content (in string) and from loaded html in web view and find expected page.

**Problem:** I am opening a login page for user. User adds credentials and hit login button. If credentials are valid, there would be redirection from login page to some other intermediate page with same URL but behaves different on situation. First time user logs in, it shows authorization page with Accept button. Once user clicks button, user moves to expected final page. If user logs after first time, intermediate page would be blank and after some time it goes to final expected page.

I need to find a logic which detects intermediate page has authorization info or has blank page. I can not identify it using URL since intermediate page has same URL for both scenario. So, thinking of reading HTML content of page. How do I do that?

I am targeting iOS, Android and Windows as cross platform xamarin forms application.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package System.Net.Http into your PCL and get the HTML content of the page that way.

```
HttpClient hpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage requestMessage = await hpClient.GetAsync("http://google.com");
string HTMLContent = await requestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Note: To install the System.Net.Http package you will need to double click your PCL solution, Go to General > Current Profile and change it to PCL 4.5 - Profile 111.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please review it. I am going to webpage by redirection so above solution could not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would still think how else you can do what you need but here is one of methods you can use.

Subscribe for Navigated event. Inside it WebNavigatedEventArgs parameter has UrlWebViewSource member Source which points to Url. You can read from it.

Another option is to check CanGoBack. If it was redirection this member should be true.

To read content of the page you need to implement custom renderer.

Comment: If you provide sample solution to I might be able to help more.